# How To Extract Tokens from String?

Tags: c++, regex, string, split

**Edit: May someone add a regex solution? I was looking on the following regex:**

```
[\(\)!*-+^]
```

I had the a function that extracts tokens from a text according to the special chars I declared in its body.

There are 2 problems in the function:

**1)** It doesn't print the special chars.

**2)** It outputs wrong when two special chars are next to each other

So I made a change, which fixed problem 1 (As I saw from the result of some tests)
But doesn't fix number 2, any help?

Note: I am using C++11 standard and not looking to use boost

**Example:** Given: `a+(b*c)` I am expecting: `a,+,(,b,*,c,)`

Given: `a+b` I am expecting: `a,+,b`

Given: `ab+` I am expecting: `ab,+`

Given: `a b+` I am expecting: `a b,+`

Comment: Can you show some example inputs and your expected outputs?

Comment: It is because you are skipping the special character when doing last_pos = pos + 1. You can cout the special character which is str[pos]

Comment: @CoryKramer Updated: I have added some edge cases, please refresh

Comment: @armagedescu if I don't do last_pos=pos+1 the code will run without a stop

Comment: @CoryKramer any help please?

Comment: I prefer using regex if possible

Comment: @daniel I didn's say to not increase the last_pos. I only told why you miss the separator. The second problem solve by comparing pos and last_pos and then print the substr if it contains anything.

Comment: @armagedescu I didn't get you, may you kindly make the edit of the line

Comment: @daniel  print the substr only if it contains anything. It means the pos is bigger than last_pos.

Comment: @daniel, did you find solution to this problem?

Comment: Why did you edit out the attempted code from the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a regex solution that should parse the tokens you want:

```
void find(std::string str)
{
    static const std::regex r(R"(\+|\^|-|\*|!|\(|\)|([\w|\s]+))");
    std::copy( std::sregex_token_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), r, 0),
               std::sregex_token_iterator(),
               std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/96xo4d).

Here's an [explanation](https://regex101.com/r/eML5mM/2).

Note that this is not a good idea if you want to do general purpose parsing. The regex will quickly become unwieldy (if it's not already), and there are much better tools available to do this for you.

Comment: Thanks but it prints two extra empty lines

Comment: One at the top and one at the end

Comment: Right, I forgot to escape the `^`. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you, one small thing, what if I don't want to print them but to save them to an existing vector?

Comment: The last argument would be something like `std::back_inserter(v)` where `v` is a `vector<string>`

Answer (score 0):

You're not handling empty strings well.  Before processing the empty string, check to make sure it isn't empty.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

using std::string;
using std::stringstream;
using std::vector;

namespace {

// Parse a string into a vector of tokens by special characters.
auto find(string str) -> vector<string> {
    auto result = vector<string>{};
    auto pos = string::size_type{};
    auto last_pos = string::size_type{};

    while ((pos = str.find_first_of("+^-*!()", last_pos)) != string::npos) {
        // Is there a token before the special character?
        if (pos - last_pos > 0) {
            result.push_back(str.substr(last_pos, pos - last_pos));
        }

        last_pos = pos + 1;

        // Add the special character as a token.
        result.push_back(str.substr(pos, 1));
    }

    auto last = str.substr(last_pos);

    // Is there a trailing token after the last found special character?    
    if (!last.empty()) {
        result.push_back(str.substr(last_pos));
    }

    return result;
}

// Helper routine.
// Join a vector of strings together using a given separator.
auto join(vector<string> const& v, string sep) -> string {
    auto ss = stringstream{};
    auto first = true;

    for (auto const& s : v) {
        if (first) {
            ss << s;
            first = false;
        } else {
            ss << sep << s;
        }
    }

    return ss.str();
}

// Helper routine.
// Returns a string representing the tokenized string.
auto check(string s) -> string {
    auto v = find(s);
    auto result = join(v, ",");
    return result;
}

} // anon

int main() {
    // Unit tests to check that the string parses and tokenizes into the expected string.
    assert(check("a+(b*c)") == "a,+,(,b,*,c,)");
    assert(check("a+b") == "a,+,b");
    assert(check("ab+") == "ab,+");
    assert(check("a b+") == "a b,+");
    assert(check("a") == "a");
    assert(check("aa") == "aa");
    assert(check("+") == "+");
    assert(check("++") == "+,+");
    assert(check("a+") == "a,+");
    assert(check("+a") == "+,a");
    assert(check("") == "");
}
```

Comment: Adding the comments frequently in code is better for visitors rather than showing a bunch of code.

Comment: Thanks, may someone point if there is a solution using regex

Comment: Please add that request to the question as well.

Comment: @daniel • a regex is not a good general purpose parser.  If you need a general purpose parser, consider the [Spirit Parser Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirit_Parser_Framework) which can do general parsing by supplying a grammar.

Comment: @cigien edited the question and added possible regex

Comment: @Eljay thanks but I am not interested in using external parsers